# Passing PChar's between a Delphi 2007 DLL and an XE6 EXE

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a DLL written in Delphi 2007 that I can't, for various reason, convert to being compiled in XE6.

I have written a wee test app in XE6 that calls the DLL, and that's all fine, but I need to pass string data from the DLL to the exe, and I am using a PCHAR to do this.
However, consuming the PCHAR in the XE6 exe is proving to be a bit of a pain.

I read somewhere that in D2007 a PCHAR is actually a PANSICHAR, so I tried using a PANSICHAR and I make a call to the DLL but it just returns an empty string!

I have tried various other types like PWIDECHAR, String, WideString, ShortString and PCHAR.
PCHAR does return something that looks like a Wide String, but I am not sure if it actually is because it didn't cast when I tried it :-)

So I am wondering what I am doing wrong? Am I passing the wrong type from the D2007 DLL? Should I be doing the consumption of the data differently in XE6?

**-- EDIT --**
Ok, I didnt get any results based on Remy's idea, so I have included my code this time and I am sure the solution will be obvious to someone. I appreciate the help :-)

This is the code for the DLL which is written in D2007:

```
library mydll;

  uses
    SysUtils

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage:PAnsiChar);
stdcall;

var
  FOnCommandProc: TOnCommandProc = nil;

procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc);
stdcall;
begin
  FOnCommandProc := CallbackProc;
end;

procedure OnEventMessage(Data: String);
var
 BuffSize: Integer;
 sOut: string;
 oData : PAnsiChar;
begin

  sOut:=Data;
  BuffSize:=SizeOf(Char)*(Length(sOut)+1);
  getmem(oData, BuffSize);
  FillChar(oData^,BuffSize,0);

  if (Length(sOut)>0) then
  begin
    Move(sOut[1], PAnsiChar(oData)^, BuffSize);
    FOnCommandProc(oData);
  end;
end;

procedure TryTheEvent;
begin
  OnEventMessage('Hello');
end;

exports
  SetOnCommandProc name 'SetOnCommandProc',
  TryTheEvent name 'TryTheEvent';
end.
```

This is the calling EXE code written in Delphi XE6:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage:PAnsiChar); stdcall;

  procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc; sMessage:PAnsiChar); stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';
  procedure TryTheEvent; stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    class procedure MyOnCommandProc(sMessage:PAnsiChar); stdcall; static;
    procedure OnCommand(sMessage : PAnsiChar);

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryTheEvent;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(@MyOnCommandProc,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(nil,0);
end;

class procedure TForm1.MyOnCommandProc(sMessage:PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  TForm1(sMessage).OnCommand(sMessage);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnCommand(sMessage :PAnsiChar);
begin
  showmessage(sMessage);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Expecting us to help you with your code when you don't include your code. It's hard to see what's wrong when there's nothing to examine.

Comment: Your implementation of `OnEventMessage` is needlessly complex. It can be simply `begin FOnCommandProc(PChar(Data)); end;`  Your question is really east to answer but I cannot do so because it is closed because you would not supply code.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. The one that is burning you is a function declaration mismatch. The DLL implementaton of SetOnCommandProc has one parameter. You import a function with two parameters. On top of that the cast of sMessage to TForm1 is quite wrong. The question actually has nothing at all to do with ANSI/Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes David!! I must have inadvertently removed the missing parameter at some stage of frustration:-)
However, can you offer more to your comment "On top of that the cast of sMessage to TForm1 is quite wrong"  as I am missing something..

Jeremy

Comment: From the answer I would like to post when the question is re-opened: *The EXE code performs an erroneous cast `TForm1(sMessage)`. A `PAnsiChar` is never an object reference.*

Comment: So we got the question re-opened. I've now added the answer that I wrote earlier in the day. And of course now that Remy can see the code he is able to see all the same issues that I do, and has edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a number of problems with your code. Specifically:

- `SetOnCommandProc` has a single parameter. You declare it in the EXE with two.
- You implement `TryTheEvent` with the `register` calling convention in the DLL, but then declare it as `stdcall` in the EXE.
- The implementation of `OnEventMessage` is needlessly complex and in fact leaks.
- The EXE code performs an erroneous cast `TForm1(sMessage)`. A `PAnsiChar` is never an object reference.
- You use the `@` operator to obtain a function pointer. This suppresses type checking.

It is the first of these points that is giving you the most problems. But you should fix them all.

I would have the DLL like this:

```
library mydll;

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage: PAnsiChar); stdcall;

var
  FOnCommandProc: TOnCommandProc = nil;

procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc); stdcall;
begin
  FOnCommandProc := CallbackProc;
end;

procedure OnEventMessage(Data: AnsiString);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnCommandProc) then
    FOnCommandProc(PAnsiChar(Data));
end;

procedure TryTheEvent; stdcall;
begin
  OnEventMessage('Hello');
end;

exports
  SetOnCommandProc, TryTheEvent;

end.
```

And the EXE like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    class procedure MyOnCommandProc(sMessage: PAnsiChar); stdcall; static;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage: PAnsiChar); stdcall;

procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc); stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';
procedure TryTheEvent; stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryTheEvent;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(MyOnCommandProc);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(nil);
end;

class procedure TForm1.MyOnCommandProc(sMessage: PAnsiChar);
begin
  ShowMessage(sMessage);
end;

end.
```

Note that I've removed the instance method `OnCommand` altogether. If you do need to call an instance method then you need to pass an instance as well as a callback function. So you might pass the instance reference to the DLL, typed as a `Pointer`, and then pass that instance reference back in the callback.

Comment: David...did you copies Remy's code?? :-) JUsT KIDDING....thank you to you bothI I certainly see now where I went wrong now....its obvious to me NOW! :-(

Comment: Ha ha. I wrote my answer while the question was still closed. I was only able to post it when remy cast the final reopen vote. Anyway, I do think you should accept whichever answer you feel is the best.

Answer (score 3):

In D2007 and earlier, `String` is an alias for `AnsiString` and `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`.

In D2009 and later, `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString` and `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`.

If you want an XE6 project to call into a D2007 DLL, you will have to declare the DLL types/parameters using `PAnsiChar` instead of `PChar`.  And be sure to use `AnsiString` or other `AnsiChar`-based memory allocation when passing `PAnsiChar` pointers into the DLL.  If you are still having trouble, then please update your question to show the actual code that is not working.

**Edit**: Based on the code you have now shown, try this code instead:

D2007 DLL:

```
library mydll;

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage: PChar; pUserData: Pointer); stdcall;

var
  FOnCommandProc: TOnCommandProc = nil;
  FOnCommandUserData: Pointer = nil;

procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc; UserData: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  FOnCommandProc := CallbackProc;
  FOnCommandUserData := UserData;
end;

procedure OnEventMessage(Data: String);
begin
  if (Data <> '') and Assigned(FOnCommandProc) then
  begin
    FOnCommandProc(PChar(Data), FOnCommandUserData);
  end;
end;

procedure TryTheEvent; stdcall;
begin
  OnEventMessage('Hello');
end;

exports
  SetOnCommandProc name 'SetOnCommandProc',
  TryTheEvent name 'TryTheEvent';
end.
```

XE6 app:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TOnCommandProc = procedure(sMessage: PAnsiChar; pUserData: Pointer); stdcall;

  procedure SetOnCommandProc(CallbackProc: TOnCommandProc; UserData: Pointer); stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';
  procedure TryTheEvent; stdcall; external 'mydll.dll';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    class procedure MyOnCommandProc(sMessage: PAnsiChar: pUserData: Pointer); stdcall; static;
    procedure OnCommand(sMessage : PAnsiChar);

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryTheEvent;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(@MyOnCommandProc, Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetOnCommandProc(nil, nil);
end;

class procedure TForm1.MyOnCommandProc(sMessage: PAnsiChar; pUserData: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  TForm1(pUserData).OnCommand(sMessage);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnCommand(sMessage: PAnsiChar);
begin
  ShowMessage(sMessage);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You are suggesting that the asker does what he states he has already tried.

Comment: I am stating a fact of what is needed. If he already tried it, then obviously he did not do it correctly.

Comment: Well, more likely the problem is that the original DLL is broken. Sounds like it is returning `PAnsiChar` which sounds dubious to say the least.

Comment: If the DLL were broken then I would expect the OP to have problems using it in D2007 as well.  Since that is probably not the case, I have to suspect the problem is in how the XE6 app is using the DLL.

Comment: If `PAnsiChar` is not working either, then it is hard to tell what is wrong without some code. It is probably a `PWideChar`/`PAnsiChar`issue, but probably something in the DLL or EXE code (e.g. `PAnsiChar(myString)`). Code is needed here.

Comment: wow....settle guys! :-)  I didnt include code because I thought the question was straight forward. I will do what Remy suggests. I suspect the issue is not the XE6 end but the D2007 end where I need to change my type after seeing his reply. Let you know....in the mean time....chillax :-)

Comment: I have now edited my post above to include my code.so I how it makes things clearer.

Jeremy

Comment: We are relaxed. If you had just included the code like we asked, this would have been trivial to solve.

Comment: David, now that I have added my code can you take this off hold since I should have provided enough info to answer the question now.

Comment: Forget the above comment, I didnt see your comments further up the page.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. We need another vote. Then I have an answer for you already written,

Comment: A bit odd to write `if (Data <> '')`. Why make it impossible to send an empty string?

Comment: Because the OP's original code was checking for `Length(sOut)>0` before triggering the event. It is not uncommon for people to skip passing blank data to custom events. It depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: Actually I think that was a mistake. I think the event was meant to be outside the test. I think that test was to avoid using s[1] when s was nil. But I see what you mean.